# Comparative cost of public transport

Tags: transportation

Is there a good database comparing the cost of public transport? I found [this one](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/cost-of-public-transportation-around-the-world.html) and [this one](https://www.priceoftravel.com/595/public-transportation-prices-in-80-worldwide-cities/) but they cite no sources so have no idea how they were constructed. Also, it is for a given period. Ideally the database should have more years. I've searched in OECD and world bank without success. Help please! :)

Answer (score 2):

The world bank group has a Urban Transport Data Analysis Tool (UT-DAT) located here: https://www.worldbank.org/en/topic/transport/publication/urban-transport-data-analysis-tool-ut-dat1

It has an excel file that has some data.  There is also Data.world  https://data.world/datasets/transportation

There is Global Mass Transit website but its a paid service with some free options:   https://www.globalmasstransit.net/index.php

This Wiki site here might be a better option for you on free public transportation data links: 
https://www.transitwiki.org/TransitWiki/index.php/Publicly-accessible_public_transportation_data

The world bank has Public private partnerships investment in transport (current US$). 
Which are contractual relationships typically between a state or local government, who are the owners of most transportation infrastructure, and a private company.

https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/IE.PPN.TRAN.CD

This looks like a hard find.